# collecting annual aggregated data for later quick access

Tags: sql, oracle, scheduled-tasks, data-warehouse, materialized-views

I have a number of sql queries which take `year` as a parameter and generate various annual reports for the given year.

Those queries are quite cumbersome and take a considerable amount of time to execute (20 min - 40 min).

In order to give my users the ability to view annual report whenever they need to, I am considering to pre-execute these queries and store the results for later use.

One solution would be to schedule execution of these queries and insert the results in some temp tables.

But I am looking for more clever approach one that would not involve writing dozens of execute immediate  statements or custom inserts for all these queries.

Any idea would be appreciated. Also I don't know if materialized views can be used to that end.

expected result would be a table or a view with a year column so that a user could execute quick search for any year.

e.g.

```
product_id |annual_sales|max_price|min_price|year
124|1200,56|80|50|2019
124|1400,00|85|55|2020
```

Comment: Other than saying "yes, materialized views would generally be the technology to use", I'm not quite sure what sort of answer you'd be looking for.  Have you tried using materialized views?  Are you having a problem implementing them?  Getting query rewrite to work?  Something else?

Comment: @JustinCave first, I wasn't sure that MV was the right way to go - you covered that. one concern that I have with MV is that (if I understand it correctly) I should rewrite my queries by removing `where myyear=year` clause and grouping by the year. but results for a single year take 40 min to complete...wouldn't be the group by query problematically slow...also ideally I need to collect past years data once a year..and not to recalculate for every year that had been already calculated...can I do that with Materialized Views?

Comment: @JustinCave would you take a look at my new question, and tell me if your advice for MV still stands ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64302432/creating-materialized-view-for-annual-report-based-on-slow-function?noredirect=1#comment113707409_64302432 thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A materialized view would be a great option for what you are looking to do. This way you can write the query once for the view, then have the data in the materialized view refresh as often as you'd like. You can have a job that refreshes the data once per night, on the weekends, or whatever frequency you choose.

After the materialized view is created, you can also add indexes on top of the materialized view to assist with query performance if you so choose.

A quick example on how to create a materialized view can be seen below.

```sql
CREATE TABLE sale
(
    product_id     NUMBER,
    sale_date      DATE,
    sale_amount    NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO sale (product_id, sale_date, sale_amount)
     VALUES (124, DATE '2019-02-01', 40.25);

INSERT INTO sale (product_id, sale_date, sale_amount)
     VALUES (124, DATE '2019-02-01', 80.99);

INSERT INTO sale (product_id, sale_date, sale_amount)
     VALUES (124, DATE '2020-02-01', 30.50);

INSERT INTO sale (product_id, sale_date, sale_amount)
     VALUES (124, DATE '2020-02-01', 46.75);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW sales_summary
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
AS
      SELECT product_id,
             SUM (sale_amount)                 AS annual_sales,
             MAX (sale_amount)                 AS max_price,
             MIN (sale_amount)                 AS min_price,
             EXTRACT (YEAR FROM sale_date)     AS year
        FROM sale
    GROUP BY product_id, EXTRACT (YEAR FROM sale_date);
```

Result

```sql
select * from sales_summary;

   PRODUCT_ID    ANNUAL_SALES    MAX_PRICE    MIN_PRICE    YEAR
_____________ _______________ ____________ ____________ _______
          124          121.24        80.99        40.25    2019
          124           77.25        46.75         30.5    2020
```

Comment: The issue I see with MVs for this use case is that the output data is only summarized annually, and there doesn't appear to be a need to re-compute past years. An MV makes most sense when you need to re-compute the _entire_ result set. Given that the data is only computed annually, use of fast refresh MVs with MV Logs doesn't seem practical, either.