# creating materialized view for annual report based on slow function

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, materialized-views

Consider the following scenario:

I have a table with 1 million product ids `products` :

```
create table products (
pid number,
p_description varchar2(200)
)
```

also there is a *relatively slow* function

`function gerProductMetrics(pid,date) return number`

which returns some metric for the given product at given date.

there is also an annual report executed every year that is based on the following query:

```
select pid,p_description,getProductMetrics(pid,'2019-12-31') from
products
```

that query takes about 20-40 minutes to execute for a given year.

would it be correct approach to create Materialized View (MV) for this scenario using the following

```
CREATE TABLE mydates
(
    mydate     date
 
);

INSERT INTO  mydates (mydate)
     VALUES (DATE '2019-12-31');

INSERT INTO  mydates (mydate)
     VALUES (DATE '2018-12-31');

INSERT INTO  mydates (mydate)
     VALUES (DATE '2017-12-31');


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW metrics_summary
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
AS
      SELECT pid,
             getProductMetrics(pid,mydate      AS annual_metric,
             mydate
        FROM products,mydates
```

or it would take forever?

Also, how and how often would I update this MV?

Metrics data is required for the end of each year.

But any year's data could be requested at any time.

Note, that I have no control over the slow function - it's just a given.
thanks.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to convert the getProductMetrics functionality to pure sql and get the same data without using the function at all. I can't tell because it is unclear what it does but I've seen cases where this was perfectly possible.

Comment: @KoenLostrie I know what you mean... but sadly replacing the function(s) is not an option right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do not have a "group by" query, so you can remove that.

An MV would be most useful if you needed to recompute *all* of the data for all years. As this appears to be a summary, with no need to reprocess old data, updated only when certain threshold dates like end of year are passed, I would recommend putting the results in a normal table and only adding the updates as often as your threshold dates occur (annually?) using a stored procedure. Otherwise your MV will take longer to run and require more system resources with every execution that adds a new date.

Comment: yes you're right about `group by` - must've got carried away while writing the question...  fixed it. stored procedures was my first thought but I got some (may be wrong) advise to use MV... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64286481/collecting-annual-aggregated-data-for-later-quick-access . I have same reservations that you expressed... may be my first question was not formed well enough - may be that's why I got MV advice ....

Comment: Looking at your other question, I would not create a temp table - make it a permanent table, just like an MV would be. But where the MV would rebuild your entire result set every time, just use a stored procedure to add new data annually. No need to write "dozens of insert statements" either - just loop the procedure through a range of dates to do your initial load.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create a materialized view.  This is not just a performance issue.  It is also an archiving issue:  You don't want to run the risk that historical results could change.

My advice is to create a single table with a "year" column.  Run the query once per year and insert the rows into the new table.  This is an archive of the results.

Note:  If you want to recalculate previous years because the results may have changed (say the data is updated somehow), then you should store those results in a separate table and decide which version is the "right" version.  You may find that you want an archive table with both the "as-of" date and the "run-date" to see how results might be changing.